# How to take backup of all bookmarks in to Google Drive For Firefox and Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox

I want to take all current bookmarks save into my Google Drive. How to possible?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a browser issue.  It can be reasked at [SU].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Chrome:

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>, **Bookmark Manager** page will open in new tab. Click on **Organize**, from the dropdown menu select **Export bookmarks to HTML file...**. Save the file on your local system. Now you can save this HTML file into Google Drive.

On Firefox:

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>, A new window will popup. Click on **Import and Backup**, from the dropdown menu select **Export bookmarks to HTML file...**. Save the file on your local system. Now you can save this HTML file into Google Drive.

Comment: serenesat ,Thank you for answers.